# Transform 2 int into 1 int of 5 of lenght

Tags: c#, math, hash

This might not belong here so if I need to ask this somewhere else please tell me.

Let's say we have 10032(Will be X) and 154(Will be Y) as the input, what I would need is to get 1 int as the output. That output would also need to be of length of 4 or 5.

With the output  and either X or Y know, I need to stop anyone from discovering the formula. This is a scenario where the Y will stay the same but the X will change often.

I am reading on hash but I am unsure of which one would be the best for me. Or if a simple math formula would do the job. In the program we are currently using it in the following way : 
X + Y * 2 / 3 and then rounding to the lower number.

This solution would also need a very low amount of collision.

Thanks

Comment: Homework? OK, but if so should tag it as such.  Also, "With the output and one of the ID" not very clear. I think you mean one of the inputs, X or Y. Is that correct?

Comment: Not homework just cannot describe why I need it, company policy.

Comment: Changed the sentence hopefully it is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that a good approach to minimise collisions would be to use modulus 10^6 after whatever operation you perform on both numbers.

The hard part would be the operation between the original ints, but look up theory about hashing and I am sure you can find nice suggestions.

In order to make it truly difficult to reverse, you could perform operations in several stages, each one of them depending on the results of the previous one. Just an idea...

Comment: Or, adding to my answer, you could hash it with a proven hashing algorithm such as SHA2 or even simpler ones like MD5, and then modularise the results to your length requirements. Does it make sense?

Comment: Not sure what modularise mean

Comment: "modularise" - Do modulo 100000 or something like that. Just be aware that you can get results that are too short after modulo. So, you could try something lijke modulo 10000 + some 4 digit number, would guarantee 4 to 5 digit result.

Comment: I mean applying the modulus operator to keep numbers below a range, as in (16 mod 4) = 0, but (15 mod 4) = 3 and (17 mod 4) = 1. Normally implemented in programming languages with the operator `%`. Look clock or modular arithmetic up ;)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: Use a prime number for your modulo (the number after the mod operator). Without going into theory this has less potential to generate collisions.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks all your information was enough to allow me to research it correctly

Answer (score 2):

For this question, you may have better luck at [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) but here are a few thoughts.

1. It sounds like you want to map a 5-digit int and 3-digit int to a 4- or 5-digit int with the qualifications that:
     a. The producing algorithm is difficult to determine given the input
     b. There are few collisions
2. Given some function F(x,y) there are 100,000,000 combinations of x and y if x and y are between 1 and 5 digits and 1 and 3 respectively.
3. If F(x,y) produces a 5-digit number there are 100,000 possible solutions .
4. On average this would mean that each value of F(x,y) has 1,000 combinations of x, y that map to it.
5. So at best case this means that given x1, y1 and x2, y2 the odds that F(x1,y1)=F(x2,y2) is 1/1000, which for most uses I can think of would be considered too high.

Considering those things, probably the simplest idea would be a basic modular ring over the ints like Oscar mentioned. For your modulo you should pick the greatest prime number with the number of digits you want to keep. For instance if you want a 5 digit result use 99,877. Or if you wanted to avoid collisions and go with 9-digits, you would use 999,999,733. You can use a [prime list](http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/liste_online_en.php) to look up which prime you use for your modulo.

Comment: I though of Cryptography Stack Exchange but I was afraid my level is too low for it. Thx for the thoughts

Answer (score 1):

decimal d = (X * Y) - (reverse X * reverse Y);
(When I say reverse 10032 would be 23001)

Then take the first 4 or 5 digits if there are more.

Or you could make a string that would look like this:
10032154 and then use a Hash method and then take the first 4 or 5 digits?
(You could reverse this too so the string is: 45123001)

BTW why do you need to take the 1st 4 or 5 digits?
Reducing the amount of digits will cause the chance of collusion to increase.

Comment: They will represent users but need to change depending on the second number and over 5 people cannot see the difference easily.

Comment: Sorry English is my second language sometimes I am unclear. I meant over 5 numbers the eye take too long to identify who is who.